# pypy import clr fails on Windows

Tags: python, .net, windows, pypy, python.net

I tried pythonnet with `pypy` on Win10. It builds fine, but then fails to `import clr`. The crash happens after this call in the screenshot.

Any tips/tools for debugging this?

[image]

```
pypy
Python 2.7.12 (aff251e54385, Nov 09 2016, 17:54:55)
[PyPy 5.6.0 with MSC v.1500 32 bit] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>> import clr
Attempting to load 'Python.Runtime' using standard binding rules.
'Python.Runtime' not found using standard binding rules.
Attempting to load Python.Runtime from: 'C:\Python\pypy2-v5.6.0-win32\site-packages\Python.Runtime.dll'.
Success loading 'Python.Runtime' from: 'C:\Python\pypy2-v5.6.0-win32\site-packages\Python.Runtime.dll'.
RPython traceback:
  File "pypy_module_cpyext_2.c", line 26114, in type_realize
  File "pypy_module_cpyext_2.c", line 31744, in _type_realize
Fatal RPython error: AssertionError

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

[Here is the detailed thread about the issue](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/330)

Comment: I think it is a bug

Comment: Does https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/issues/3117/fatal-rpython-error-when-importing-opencv help?

Comment: Looks like https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/issues/2486/ is the exact same thing here!

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a [known critical issue](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/issues/2486/) with `pypy`.

I would suggest updating to `Python3` as `Python2.7` became [unsupported](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/) from the beginning of 2020, even if this doesn't fix your issue.